# How to convert dynamically loaded webforms usercontrol to mvc razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm porting an existing custom CMS written in webforms to MVC4 ideally keeping the CMS database schema and data intact. I'm using the url to determine which page is requested, and which template is used. Templates are primarily used for different layout and content 'fields'.

In my webforms app I have a base class `PageTemplate : UserControl`

I have a default.aspx which looks at the path of the request, pulls it from the db, then uses the TemplateId property to dynamically load the usercontrol, add the db content to a property and then add to a placeholder on the page

```
p = CMSPage.Select(fullPath);
myTemplate = LoadControl("~/templates/template_" + p.TemplateId.ToString + ".ascx");
myTemplate.Content = p;
phTemplate.Controls.Add(myTemplate);
```

In the usercontrols `Init` event I populate Literal tags with content from the CMS - which means that I can have server control buttons and interactions and still handle postbacks - all encapsulated within the usercontrol

I have about 20 templates, most are render only, some are interactive. I want to migrate to Razor as the view engine.

1) what is the best MVC way of loading partialviews based on dynamic content, and passing the CMS content as the Model to the view? Is it a single CMSpage controller with partials for each template? Or a controller for each template?

2) What is the most structured MVC way of handling Posts from within a template partial: methods on the single CMS controller? controller for each template?

3) pseudo code welcomed!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can follow a similar approach to your user control approach.  Redirect to an action method, which chooses which partial view to return depending on the template ID.  The action method can take the partial ID and do `return PartialView("View" + templateID.ToString());`.  It would also be possible to dynamically load partial views from the view using `Html.Action` too. Partial view's can also be loaded and streamed to the client using JQuery using $.ajax too, in case you needed dynamic content loading.
2. Either define the form in the partial view, or have one global partial view that accepts a FormCollection (a generic way to refer to the posted back form).  You can use some ID that gets posted back to figure out the template response.  If you can, having the form in the template might be a lot nicer and easier to configure.  However, the latter would be more complex, but if you want a generic CMS solution, the latter is a way to achieve that.

There is no one-size-fits-all solution for this; it's hard to provide advice with only a small glimpse of the product.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Would you recommend separate Action Methods in a single CMS controller to handle form posts, or split out into multiple controllers?